# How to put an overlay on a video

Tags: python, opencv, video, overlay

I am currently working in Python and using OpenCV's videocapture and cv.imshow to show a video. I am trying to put an overlay on this video so I can draw on it using cv.line, cv.rectangle, etc. Each time the frame changes it clears the image that was drawn so I am hoping if I was to put an overlay of some sort on top of this that it would allow me to draw multiple images on the video without clearing. Any advice? Thanks ahead!

Answer (score 0):

What you need are 2 Mat objects- one to stream the camera (say Mat_cam), and the other to hold the overlay (Mat_overlay).

When you draw on your main window, save the line and Rect objects on Mat_overlay, and make sure that it is not affected by the streaming video

When the next frame is received, Mat_cam will be updated and it'll have the next video frame, but Mat_overlay will be the same, since it will not be cleared/refreshed with every 'for' loop iteration. Adding Mat_overlay and Mat_cam using Weighted addition will give you the desired result.

Comment: I tried this but I keep getting this error:                     error: ..\..\..\modules\core\src\arithm.cpp:1287: error: (-209) The operation is neither 'array op array' (where arrays have the same size and the same number of channels), nor 'array op scalar', nor 'scalar op array' in function cv::arithm_op          .... Could it be because I'm using the videoCapture function to load my video?

Comment: No. It's because the two Mat objects that you're adding should have the same size and same number of channels, ie both should be 3 channel images

Comment: Sorry for another bad question. But how do I know how many channels are in my video? I tried to use the copy function but it wouldn't let me with the videoCapture function.

Comment: If you're using VideoCapture directly to save image to your Mat, and havent used cvtColor, it should be a 3 channel BGR 8UC3 (8bit unsigned char 3 channel) image

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I have understood your question properly.What I got from your question is that you want the overlay to remain on your frame, streamed from Videocapture,  for that one simple solution is to declare your "Mat_cam"(camera streaming variable) outside the loop that is used to capture frames so that "Mat_cam" variable will not be freed every time you loop through it.